# Lexicographical order on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ equipped with the lexicographical order $\leq$ :

$$ \forall \big( (a,b),(a',b') \big) \in \big( \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \big)^{2}, (a,b) \leq (a',b') \, \Leftrightarrow \, \big( (a<a') \; \mathrm{or} \; (a=a' \; \mathrm{and} \; b \leq b') \big) $$

The question I am interested in is the following : let $M$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ that is bounded above. Can we say that $M$ has a greatest element ? and what can we say about $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Here is my try : to begin with, $M$ is bounded above means that there exist $(u,v) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that :

$$ \forall (a,b) \in M, \, (a,b) \leq (u,v) $$

Using what I know from $\mathbb{N}$, I would like to introduce the sets

$$ S_{1} = \left\lbrace k \in \mathbb{N}, \, (k,\cdot) \in M \right\rbrace $$

and

$$ S_{2} = \left\lbrace j \in \mathbb{N}, \, (\cdot,j) \in M \right\rbrace $$

Both $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and are bounded above. Therefore, let $s_{1}^{+}$ (respectively $s_{2}^{+}$) be the greatest element of $S_{1}$ (respectively $S_{2}$). Then, $(s_{1}^{+},s_{2}^{+})$ could be a candidate for a greatest element but there is no reason for $(s_{1}^{+},s_{2}^{+})$ to be in $M$, is there ?

About $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, I believe that we can still equip $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ with the lexicographical order and expect that every non-empty subset bounded above has a greatest element.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $A=\{(1,n): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. $A$ is bounded above (for example $\forall (a,b) \in A (a,b) \leq (2,1)$), but hasn't the greatest element. The same counterexample for $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I did not think of that ! Thanks !!!

Comment: (A simple way to fix this issue is to consider $(a,b) \prec (a',b')$ is $a'+b'>a+b$, or equality holds and one compares by $\texttt{LEX}$. Then, the example in the question is not bounded, and of course the answer to the OPs question is "Yes". )